# time complexity for code and an order of magnitude improvement

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have the following problem:

1. For the following code, with reason, give the time complexity of the function.
2. Write a function which performs the same task but which is an order-of magnitude improvement in time complexity. A function with greater (time or space) complexity will not get credit.

Code:

```
int something(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
             temp = a[i];
             for(int j = i; j > 0; j--)
                a[j] = a[j-1];
             a[0] = temp;
        }
}
```

I'm thinking that since the `temp = a[i]` assignment in the worst case is done `n` times, a time complexity of `n` is assigned to that, and `a[j] = a[j-1]` is run `n(n+1)/2` times so a time complexity value of `(n2+n)/2` is assigned to that, summing them returns a time complexity of `n+0.5n2+0.5n`, removing the constants would lead to `2n+n2` and a complexity of `n2`.

For the order of magnitude improvement:

```
int something(int[] a) {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (a[i] % 2 == 0) answer = a[i] + answer;
       else answer = answer + a[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       a[i] = answer.charAt(i);
}
```

The code inside the first for-loop is executed `n` times and in the second for-loop `n` times, summing gives a time complexity figure of `2n`.

Is this correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your function is to arrange a list with all the even numbers at the beginning of the list and then followed by the odd numbers.

For the first function the complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** as you have specified.

But for the second function the complexity is **O(n)** if the operator `+` which is used for appending is implemented as a constant time operation. Usually the append operator `+` is implemented as a constant time operation without any hidden complexity. So we can conclude that the second operation takes **O(n)** time.